# Drawer layout (navigation menu) in Xamarin Forms without using Master-Detail page

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm still learning and developing a cross platform app. I've found many tutorials and answers here on creating a Xamarin Forms Navigation menu using Master-Detail page. I've created one too. But I'm looking for alternatives ways to create a navigation menu without using master-detail page.

So, has anyone experimented or know how to create a navigation page without using Master-Detail page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SlideOverKit. Its free from Xam Consulting.

[Find it here](http://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: Thanks @Steve Chadbourne for this. Can it be used on multiple screens without code replication?